# Why can't Compiler Explorer find <math.h>?

Tags: c, arm, math.h, armclang, compiler-explorer

I am trying to [compile a C module](https://godbolt.org/z/81o7xPnv9) that includes `math.h` on Compiler Explorer, targeted at the ARM architecture. The compiler complains that it cannot find `math.h` regardless of the `armclang` version I am using.

How can I get CE to find and include `math.h`?

```
#include <math.h>
```

- 

```
<source>:1:10: fatal error: 'math.h' file not found
#include <math.h>
         ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: There are two possibilities: either the C libraries are not installed at all for ARM, or the compiler wasn't told the proper path (missing environment variable ?)

Comment: You have a bunch of command-line options there which affect the ABI. Maybe Compiler Explorer doesn't have the libraries installed for the specific target you requested.

Comment: No such problem with GCC. Anyway, the question is to the godbolt owners

Comment: @EugeneSh.: in what way does this answer ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust It is a comment, and not an answer, which is providing some extra info. `GCC` on the same "Compiler Explorer" has a different behavior.

Comment: It's caused by the `--target=arm-arm-none-eabi` command-line option.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: clearer now.

Comment: For reference, issue reported here: https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/issues/3890#issue-1310598955